# Where docker stores mysql settings

Tags: mysql, docker

I am facing one issue with docker, L am using laradock docker env for laravel. Since it has issue with mysql version I had to run those command:

```
$ docker-compose exec mysql bash
$ mysql -u root -p

ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' indentified WITH mysql_native_password BY 'root';
```

Also imported database through http://localhost:8080 and phpmyadmin

So I am trying to reproduce this issue again, so I deleted everything from docker with

```
$ docker system prune
```

but when I rebuild the containers

```
sudo docker-compose up -d nginx mysql phpmyadmin  workspace
```

My previous database is loaded again.

So my question would be how to delete db and MySQL settings, so I can execute the `alter` command and import database again.

Overall I am trying to determine  if this issue with MySQL will occur on another platform again, so I am trying to reproduce it from scratch and that is why I need to reset completely MySQL env and databases.
So not sure where MySQL settings are stored and how to delete them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL is storing most of the important information of your container [in a volume](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/1612c574f921f7f1afc13763ce9011fd8e130b19/8.0/Dockerfile.debian#L87).

Now, the command:

```sh
docker system prune
```

do not remove the volumes, per default.

If you also want to remove them, you can run:

```sh
docker system prune --volumes
```

---

If you do want to list or act on those specific volumes:

```
docker volume --help
```

would give you all the commands on volumes like `rm`, `ls`, ...

Comment: so i have to do docker volume rm laradock_mysql, for example?

Comment: Exactly, yes. If the container that was attached to it is removed already it should not give any issue. If it is not, `docker volume` will complain about it, so you'll just have to stop and remove the incriminated container.

Comment: ok i will try and accept the answer in few minues

Comment: for some reason  database is loaded again, i stopped all contrainers, did docker system prune and docker system prune --volumes, but when i rebuild containers database is loaded again?

Comment: Then it was not that volume. Just remove them all

Comment: tnx looks like i forgot to remove images some how